# C# - How can I duplicate this "Access denied" to folder / file behavior

Tags: c#, file-permissions

I have a program, "Folder Protect".
It locks folders, make them invisible, impossible to delete, impossible to write things to.
I would like to duplicate the program behavior for the locking folder.

Here's some images of the folder locking:
the alert it gives after locking a folder and trying to access it:
http://img841.imageshack.us/i/pic1yo.png/

images of the security tab before locking:

http://img9.imageshack.us/i/sectabbeforelock.png/

http://img256.imageshack.us/i/advbeforelock.png/

http://img403.imageshack.us/i/ownertabbeforelock.png/

Images of the security tab after locking:

http://img62.imageshack.us/i/sectabafterlock.png/

http://img826.imageshack.us/i/advafterlock.png/

http://img573.imageshack.us/i/ownertabafterlock.png/

What the program does:

the program removes any permissions and also changes the ownership - without the possibility that the user will change ownership

as you can see in the owner tab:
"Unable to display current owner."

trying to change owner will result in:
"Windows Security - Unable to set new owner on New Folder. Access is denied."

I tried to use the "subinacl" tool to check if it is possible to change the folder owner and it gives me the following error when trying to display the ownership or change it:
"CreateFile error: 5"

Is it possible to duplicate this behavior?
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Why don't you reverse engineer this "Folder Protect" program?

Comment: don't know reverse engineering..

Answer (score 1):

It will definitely be possible - but it might require some PInvoke calls.

For starting you off in the right direction, here are some articles:

- Here's quite an old article on ACL using Microsoft.Win32.Security - http://weblogs.asp.net/cumpsd/archive/2004/02/08/69403.aspx
- Microsoft's advice on ACL using ActiveDirectory in C# - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/899553

Hope these help